# LINQ CROSS JOIN Error

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I got this error

> Object of type '`` System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[XXX.Model.Cust_ProfileTbl] ``' cannot
>   be converted to type
>   '`` System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1XXX.Core.Model.Cust_ProfileTbl] ``'.

When I tried `CROSS JOIN`ing these 2 tables with LINQ. Could anyone advise what should I do?

```
var Cust_ProfileTbl = service.DBContext.Set<Cust_ProfileTbl>();
var Cust_GroupTbl = service.DBContext.Set<Cust_GroupTbl>();

var test =
from cg in Cust_GroupTbl
from c in Cust_ProfileTbl
select new { intCustGroup = cg.intCustGroup, bintAccountNo = c.bintAccountNo };
```

Cust_ProfileTbl.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
namespace XXXX.Core.Model
{
    [Table("Cust_ProfileTbl")]
    public partial class Cust_ProfileTbl  
    {
        [Key]
        public long bintAccountNo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Cust_GroupTbl.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
namespace xxxx.Core.Model
{
    [Table("Cust_GroupTbl")]
    public partial class Cust_GroupTbl
    {
        [Key]
        public int intCustGroup { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test =
from cg in service.DBContext.Cust_GroupTbls
from c in service.DBContext.Cust_ProfileTbls
select new { intCustGroup = cg.intCustGroup, bintAccountNo = c.bintAccountNo };
```